# Need to create an AppleScript to run as administrator without asking for password

Tags: applescript

I need to create a script to periodically delete files from a user's folder that contains files that have read only access to standard users. I have a script that works perfectly but it asks for authentication. I need it to run it unattended...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what process or command is giving you the authentication window (your question is not clear about that) but you can use do shell script for file handling without being asked for authentication.

```
do shell script "rm /path/to/file" password "<password>" with administrator privileges
```

Of course you need to have already administrator privileges.